# Redux mapStateToProps does not trigger render on object for key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

My app contains multiple conversations, each conversation has I'ts own messages.

**ChatScreen**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  return {chatMessages: state.chatMessages.messageByConversationId[state.chatMessages.conversationId]};
}
```

**On load messages reducer:**

```
export const subscribeChatMessagesSuccess: Reducer<ImmutableChatMessagesState> = (
  state: ImmutableChatMessagesState,
  { payload }: AnyAction & { payload?: SubscribeChatMessagesSuccessParams }) =>
  payload
    ? {
      ...state,
      requesting: false,
      messageByConversationId: {
        ...state.messageByConversationId,
        [payload.conversationId]: payload.chatMessages
        ,
      },
    }
    : state;
```

This works perfectly! When messages are places, screen triggers re-render.

The issue starts when I'm trying to add ChatMessage:

```
export const addChatMessage: Reducer<ImmutableChatMessagesState> = (
  state: ImmutableChatMessagesState,
  { payload }: AnyAction & { payload?: AddChatMessageParams }) => {
  return payload
    ? {
      ...state,
      messageByConversationId: {
        ...state.messageByConversationId,
        [payload.conversationId]: [...state.messageByConversationId[payload.conversationId], payload.chatMessage],
      },
    }
    : state;
```

This time, I can see the update is successful, and ChatMessages counter (on redux) is up by +1.
But the render does not trigger Screen from rendering.

What is the correct way of doing this?